# Erasing border of a TabControl in vbnet without making a CustomTabControl

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to draw my own TabControl with a different style. I have a TabControl in my form for which i have appended the event handler,

```
MainTabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
AddHandler MainTabControl.DrawItem, AddressOf TabControlPaint
```

TabControlPaint() is a method where i paint my own graphics using Bitmaps amd Buffer variables. (see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition))

I'm not inheriting from TabControl because my Application has many forms and windows and that would force me to go to each form and change the TabControl for my CustomTabControl. I would like to be able to draw my own tabs overwriting the DrawItem event.

I came up with this result [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OW0o.png), where you can see the red border, a different background color for the tabs, even different color schemes for a tab went selected.

What i can't figure out is to **erase that white 3D border that appears only on the selected tab**. I'm guessing is drawn on top when the OnPaint() method is called after the drawItem event (correct me if i'm wrong). If i debug, that white 3D border appears after the method TabControlPaint (the one i'm calling for the DrawItem event) has finished execution.

To make the question more clear, i want to design my own TabControl without overwriting the OnPaint method. What i have come up so far was not succesfull just because of that windows drawn border. Is there a way to take it off? Or do you know any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by,

`For Each page As TabPage In MainTabControl.TabPages
    AddHandler page.Paint, AddressOf test
Next`

then in my test function i draw whatever i want. In this case i just drew a rectangle. It is not efficient but i think it can be improved by double buffering.

```
Private Sub test(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim ScreenGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(MainTabControl.Handle)
    Dim myRect As Rectangle = MainTabControl.GetTabRect(MainTabControl.SelectedIndex)
    Dim borderColor As Pen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(42, 38, 37), 5)
    myRect.X -= 1
    myRect.Y -= 1
    ScreenGraphic.DrawRectangle(borderColor, myRect)
End Sub
```